# Can I bring this metal gift by airplane to Australia?

Tags: customs-and-immigration, australia, airport-security

I will visit Australia very soon. I bought this gift. Can I have problems with Customs at the Australian airport?

[image: metal figure of two people on a motorcycle]

Comment: Unless it contains commodities that aren't allowed to be imported, you will be fine.  Declare it at customs when you arrive, declare the honest value, and they will tell you if you need to pay any tax or duty on it.

Comment: If it has sharp points, it may not be allowed in hand luggage.

Answer (score 6):

For as far as I can see there are no 'non allowed' parts, like wood, food or medication.

Metal is not blocked from entering Australia.

If there is real value to this, you should report it as valuable, and might be asked to show it as they might want to confirm value and what it is made of.

Side note:
You may want/need to pack it in your hold luggage if there are sharp points or edges, or if you just want to be sure that security is not going to give you problems.
Where you pack the item does not make any difference for customs as you will collect your hold luggage before going through customs and import security (or whatever it is called officially.)